# How to isolate form's logic in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Sometimes forms has some logic: some additional data requested with ajax, it reads cookie or has a special filter. I would like to separate this logic from controller. I also would like to have forms' html in a separate file. How to achieve this?

Is it possible to make factory or service work with form?

I have an idea about implementing each form as directive. Would it be good solution?

**EDIT**:
The main goal is not to move HTML to separate file but to move the form logic out of main route controller. Is it possible to write some provider that takes care of the form so that all data queries for the form select elements (and other logic) is happening in this provider and it calls controller's function just at the end to save validated data?

Comment: Please provide more specific example .Question is too broad. There are numerous ways to include html files in angular ... custom directive, `ng-include` , nested views etc. As for the logic issues services are very helpful

Comment: As was argued by others in the downvoted answer, There are way too many different ways to implement this kind of logic for there to be one answer that is 100% correct, which functions in all scenarios, and is not a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Claies What ido you think of using difercives in this case?

Comment: I think that if I provided an answer giving you my *opinion* of one possible option, then I would be giving the impression that I was supporting an opinionated question, which I do not.  There isn't any relevant code to even form an opinion around in the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. **I also would like to have forms' html in a separate file. How to achive this?**

   You can use ready made directives like [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to include external HTML fragments, or you can have your own template-expanding [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).
2. **Is it possible to make factory or service work with form?**

   You can create any provider whose operation is dedicated to handle form(s). This is your model than an angular technique.
3. **I have an idea about implementing each form as directive. Would it be good solution?**

   If you have many forms in your application and they are playing a pivotal role, yes - having directives for forms could be termed as a *specific* solution. The pros and cons cannot be explicitly judged here since the rest of the application's character is unknown.

---

Probably [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) is one of the places you should start your research from.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is too broad. If you would like to separate the form from the controller, you need to put that form into a [directive](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp), which would allow you to put the html and javascript for the form in a separate file.

Another way to put the form html in a separate file is to use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), however, this simply lets you move the html, whereas the first method will allow you to have a separate controller for the form html.

> I have an idea about implementing each form as directive. Would it be good solution?

I believe that is THE solution you are looking for.

Comment: There is nothing that says you must use directive...that is just one alternative

Comment: Note the "believe" part of the answer. That is, in my opinion, he should use a directive, since he is trying to isolate the html AND the logic. Note that I mentioned ng-include just like you did, but I don't THINK it's what he wants.

Comment: *however, this simply lets you move the html, whereas the first method will allow you to have a separate controller* - This is wrong. You can use separate controller for included fragments. Even this controller can be dynamically loaded while inclusion.

Comment: Hmm, so essentially stick an ng-controller='newCtrl' in the ng-include html file? Seems like bad practice, given that it doesn't really utilize angular's native routing or ui-router.

Comment: You can use a separate controller without ANY problem with routing. Don't forget that angular has scope inheritance.

Comment: Nice neg, but I still don't see why you would do that over a directive.

Comment: Because its one line.